# writing a weeks diary for an office

Tags: java

I am trying to write a weeks diary for a dentist. The dentist works from 8 to 5 everyday but has one one hour break. The dentist performs 4 procedures:

- regular procedures take 15mins.,
- scaling takes 30mins.,
- filling takes 45 mins., and
- extraction takes 90 mins.

The diary should be able to book an appointment, cancel an existing appointment and check if an appointment is scheduled at a particular time. Below is a sample of what I have written so far. I decided to have a class for the 4 different procedures, then have a procedure class that contains all 4 procedures in its constructor. I don't know how to put a procedure into the diary, though.

```
// a regular procedure class that takes 15 minutes
public class RegularProcedure {
       // the duration period of a regular procedure is 15
   private  int []procedure;
    static final int  times=15;

     public RegularProcedure(){

         procedure=new int[times];
         for(int i=0; i <procedure.length;i++){
             procedure[i]=i;
         }
     }
}
```

---

```
// a scaling class that takes 30 minutes
public class Scaling {
    private int []scaling;
    static final int time=30;


    public Scaling(){

        scaling =new int[time];
        for (int i=0;i<scaling.length;i++){
            scaling[i]=i;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// a filling procedure class that taked 45 mins to complete a procedure 
public class Filling {
    private int[]filling;
    static final int time=45;


    public Filling(){

       filling=new int[time];
       for(int i=0;i<filling.length;i++){
           filling[i]=i;
       }
    }
}
```

---

```
// an extraction class that takes 90 minutes 
public class Extraction {
  private int[]extraction;
 static final int time=90;


 public Extraction(){

       extraction = new int[time];
       for(int i=0; i<extraction.length;i++){
           extraction [i]=i; 
       }
   }
}
```

---

```
// a procedure class that contains that contains the four procedures performed by d dentist
public class Procedures {
    RegularProcedure a;
    Scaling b;
    Filling c;
     Extraction d;

    public Procedures(){
        a= new RegularProcedure();
        b= new Scaling();
        c= new Filling();
        d= new Extraction();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Diary {
  private int [][]diary;
  int []diaryday;
   Procedures y;

   //a diary constructor for a week
   public Diary(){

       diary=new int[5][540];
       y=new Procedures();
     for (int i=0; i<diary.length;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j <diary[i].length;j++){
             diary[i][j]= 0; 
         }
     }
   }

   /* method to determine if dentist office is open or on 
    * break
    */
     public Boolean isOnBreak(int time){
         if(time>=0 &&time<240 ||time>=300 &&time<540){
             return false;}
         else 
             return true;
     }    
}
```

How can I put a procedure into the diary?

Comment: "i am trying to write a weeks diary for a dentist."  Tell the dentist to purchase one, unless this is homework, and if so, please add the `homework` tag.  Other tips: 1) Find your shift key and apply it once at the start of every sentence. 2) Ask a specific question. 3) Use the code formatting tags. 4) Accept some answers. 5) Post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: You should try to ask a question which is a little more specific. Try boiling this question down to a particular problem and let us know what you have already tried.

Comment: @jules am working on it . my specific questions are how do i book for eg a scaling procedure appointment in my diary class

Comment: The constructor for `class Procedures` made me itch.

Answer (score 0):

One advice, rethink the whole thing. But first, learn some basic OO programming. Your different procedures should be subclasses of `Procedure`. Learn the difference between "has a" and "is a".

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html

Comment: do you mean extending my different procedures to the procedure class

Comment: @logic yes. It will allow you to use a `ListArray<Procedure>`. You can continue from that.